# ¿Cómo quitar espacios a una cadena con php?

Tags: php

Como puedo quitar los espacios a una cadena. Es decir tomar una parte de la cadena en específico y quitarle los espacios. Estoy intentando con `preg_match`

Esta es la cadena:

```
post_type="ids" grid_id="vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5" include="53233, 53580, 27320"
```

Y quiero quitar los espacios dentro de include

Comment: Hola la sintaxis es facil: `str_replace(que_quitar, que_a_cambio, en_donde)` Pero, las variables en **php** llevan el caracter inicial **$** debes hacer algo como: `$include_limpio = str_replace(' ', '', $include);` observa que espacio entre comillas sera reemplazado por cadena nula.

Comment: @Manjias Moreno cual es la parte especifica de la cadena ??? si no sabemos ese dato tendras que usar la sugerenncia de quevedo

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez lo que quiero hacer es convertir esa cadena en un array, es decir la llave seria post_type y el valor ids, Y así por cada uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es `explode()`

```
$txt = "53233, 53580, 27320"
$num = explode(", ", $txt)
var_dump($num)
```

`$num` es un arreglo con tus números

Ojo con el espacio después de la coma. Si siempre tienes un espacio después de la coma, como te lo pongo funciona, si unas veces si, y unas veces no, la variable que buscas la obtendrás con `trim($num[n])` (n no es una variable, es un número de índice). `trim()` te servirá para que te quite los espacios al inicio y al final del texto.

---

De acuerdo a lo que complementas para tu pregunta, creo que lo podrías resolver con el siguiente patrón:

```
$txt = "post_type=\"ids\" grid_id=\"vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5\" include=\"53233, 53580, 27320\"";
$pattern = "/(\S+)=\"(.*?)\"/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches)
```

En `$matches[1]` vas a tener todos los keys, y en `$matches[2]` los valores.

```
$matches[1]:
Array
(
    [0] => post_type
    [1] => grid_id
    [2] => include
)

$matches[2]:
Array
(
    [0] => ids
    [1] => vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5
    [2] => 53233, 53580, 27320
)
```

Una vez que tienes estos dos arreglos, lo demás es trivial:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($matches[1]); $i++) {
  $val = str_replace(' ', '', $matches[2][$i]);
  $arr[$matches[1][$i]] = $val;
}
print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [post_type] => ids
    [grid_id] => vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5
    [include] => 53233,53580,27320
)
```

¿Ahora si?

Comment: Gracias @luisfer, Pero necesito convertido toda esa cadena en un array. Array
(
    [post_type] => ids
    [grid_id] => vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5
    [include] => 53233,53580,27320
)

Comment: Uhhh... eso no es una cadena. Ni tampoco es lo que preguntaste. ¿Se supone que `"post_type="ids" grid_id="vc_gid:1597790960744-b99be9fe-9a10-5" include="53233, 53580, 27320""` esto es una cadena, y quieres convertir cada "parámetro" en el key de un arreglo?

Comment: Tiene más pinta de convertirlo primero en json string y luego a Array como el dice... Pero no ha hecho ni el intento de actualizar su pregunta y colocar que espera que sea el output...

Comment: Yo entendí lo que quiere en este comentario, pero si, la pregunta está muy mal hecha. Tal como está, parece que solo era limpiar uno de sus parámetros